# Dynamically assign position absolute to li's, skipping the first

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to assign a position absolute to the li elements of different lists on a page, but not to the first li on that list. Since I cannot predict how many li's there will be in those lists, I'm doing it with jQuery like this:

```
$('.list-inline li:not(:first)').css("position", "absolute");
```

This works well on lists with more than one li. But when a list only has one li it gives it a position absolute and I don't want that. How can I fix that?

Comment: `if ($('.list-inline li').length > 1) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that, normal CSS will do.

```css
.list-inline > li:not(:first-child) {
    color: red;
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>First Item</li>
</ul>
```

- I've used `color: red;` for demonstration purposes.
- The child selector `>` makes sure that nested list items are not affected.